# Instance variable initialization inside a class flutter SQFlite

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I am trying to implement persistent storage in my flutter app using the SQFlite package.
While creating a class to do the same , I am confused at the part of initializing the db from storage. This is the code for initializing a database variable

```
_db = await db1._checkDB;
```

Now my Database class is as mentioned below

```
class DB {
  static DB db1 = DB();
  Database? _db;
  String _tableName = 'images';

  get _checkDB async {
    if (_db != null)
      return _db;
    else {
      _db = await _openDB('images.db');
      return _db;
    }
  }
}
```

My question is why can't I use the below code to initialize my database

```
_db = await _checkDB();
```

When I use the above command to initialize my Database and read from it always returns a value of null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't have a class instance?

Do it like:

```
DB database = new DB();
_db = await database.checkDB();
```